# Why it keeps showing 'Could not determine the embedded type for array `connections`'?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

i am trying to create the UserSchema and it keeps showing "Could not determine the embedded type for array `connections`. See https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#definition for more info on supported schema syntaxes."

```
//USER SCHEMA
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const { Schema } = mongoose;

export const UserSchema = new Schema({
  id: String,
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  name: String,
  surname: String,
  email: String,
  phone: String,
  password: String,
  birthdaydate: Date,
  roles: [],
  auth: {
    email: {
      valid: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    },
    facebook: {
      userid: String,
    },
    gmail: {
      userid: String,
    },
  },
  settings: {},
  photos: {
    profilePic: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Photo' },
    gallery: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Photo' }],
  }
});

//User Interface
import { Document } from 'mongoose';
import { Photo } from '../../common/interfaces/photo.interface';

export interface User extends Document{
  name: string;
  surname: string;
  email: string;
  phone: string;
  birthdaydate: Date;
  password: string;
  roles: string[];
  auth: {
    email : {
      valid : boolean,
    },
    facebook: {
      userid: string
    },
    gmail: {
      userid: string
    }
  },
  settings: {
  },
  photos: {
    profilePic: Photo;
    gallery: Photo[];
  }
}
```

why it is getting not working?

Comment: Show the full error stack

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

**You can update your UserSchema as follows**

```
export const UserSchema = new Schema({
  // ...
  roles: [String], // Specify the data type as an array of strings
  // ...
});
```

Comment: [Nest] 7840  - 07/12/2023, 6:47:34 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Invalid schema configuration: Could not determine the embedded type for array `connections`. See https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#definition for more info on supported schema syntaxes.
TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: Could not determine the embedded type for array `connections`. See https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#definition for more info on supported schema syntaxes.
    at Schema.interpretAsType (C:\Users\dk\Desktop\be tag aloola\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:1388:15)
    at Schema.path (C:\Users\

Comment: ```import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  // ...
  roles: {
    type: [String], // Specify the data type as an array of strings
    default: [], // Provide a default value if needed
  },
  // ...
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

export default User;
```
add this schema default blank array

Comment: To fix this error, you need to provide a valid schema configuration for the roles field. In Mongoose, you can define an array of strings using the Array data type and specifying the String type for each item within the array.